# How can I bind the jQuery outside events plugin's events to multiple elements?

Tags: jquery

I am using [Ben Alman's outside events plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) to close a modal window when the user clicks outside of it. This worked great until I had the need to use jQuery UI's datepicker inside the modal. Since the elements comprising the widget are not placed inside the modal, the modal closes when selecting a date, which is the correct behavior. To attempt to solve the problem, I did the following:

```
$('#modal-window, #ui-datepicker-div').one('clickoutside', function(){

    // close the modal window

});
```

That just causes the modal window to close when it is clicked.

Comment: You can prevent the event bubling on date picker if it is possible. This should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page you link in your question:

> Note that you can also utilize the `event.target` property, which references the actual element clicked, in your event handler logic. This may be useful if you want to constrain the ‘outside-ness’ of the click to certain elements or containers.

I'd use `event.target` along with `closest` to find whether the link was in the datepicker.

```
$('#modal-window').one('clickoutside', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#ui-datepicker-div').length) {
        $(this).hide(); // or whatever code you have for hiding the modal window
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried as well, but it does not solve the problem. If you click the prev/next buttons to advance the month it still closes the modal.